# python re data structure

Tags: r, data-science, python-re

**The dataset file in assets/grades.txt contains a line separated list of people with their grade in a class. Create a regex to generate a list of just those students who received a B in the course.**

```
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
        for line in grades:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if re.search('^X\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
            print(line)
    
         

assert len(grades()) == 16
```

The easy solution is to add the following regular expression '([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+): B'.
this solution is provided from [abd-elrhman-mohey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13425935/abd-elrhman-mohey)

Comment: Please provide more details, like the content of grades.txt, your expected output, and what went wrong with current code.

Comment: This is a portion of the grade.txt :                                                                        
Ronald Mayr: A
Bell Kassulke: B
Jacqueline Rupp: A 
Alexander Zeller: C
Valentina Denk: C 
Simon Loidl: B 
Elias Jovanovic: B 
Stefanie Weninger: A 
Fabian Peer: C 
Hakim Botros: B
Emilie Lorentsen: B
Herman Karlsen: C

Comment: Try `^.*B$` in place of current regex. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JLiBsl/1)

Answer (score 2):

I can see where you did go wrong my friend

first of all
grades it's the lines u don't need the for loop to get them
second of all, I don't know why did u use '^X\S*: [0-9.]+' as it seems out of what u want
you need to see if the grades ar numbers or normal grades (A B C D)
and appears from the question that u need to get B
so we can say the final code will be
for the find

```
'([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+): B'
```

and final code I guess will be

```
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
    w = '([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+): B'
    grades = re.findall(w , grades)
    return grades
```

Comment: NP your are welcom <3

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
        list_of_grades = grades.split('\n')
        print(list_of_grades)        
        list_of_students = [ li.split()[0] + ' ' + li.split()[1] for li in list_of_grades if li.split()[-1] == 'B']
        print(list_of_students)        
    
    return list_of_students
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me well as a piece of cake

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()

    # YOUR CODE HERE
    result = re.findall(': B', grades)
    return result

grades()
len(grades())
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked well for me

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    pattern=re.findall('([A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+): B',grades)
    return pattern
        
    
    #raise NotImplementedError()
```

You can check by running the following code

```
   assert len(grades()) == 16
```

To learn more about regex, visit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
    import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()

    # YOUR CODE HERE
    result = re.findall('\w* \w*: B',grades )
    return result
print(grades())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#Here is my code:

`    import re

```
 def grades():

      with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
           grades = file.read()
           a=re.findall("([\w ]*)(?=\:\sB)",grades)
           return a


# YOUR CODE HERE
raise NotImplementedError()
```

#the output looks like a this:
#['Bell Kassulke',
'',
'Simon Loidl',
'',
'Elias Jovanovic',
'',
'Hakim Botros',
'',
'Emilie Lorentsen',#

i want the output to return only names and not the spaces.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def grades():

      with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
           grades = file.read()
           pattern=re.findall("[\w ]*)(\:\ B)",grades)
           return pattern
grades()
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
    def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()

    only_B_grades = re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*\: [B]",grades)
    person = [grade_B.split(':')[0] for grade_B in only_B_grades]
    return person
    raise NotImplementedError()

grades()
```